# Datagrid displays null values for combo box control

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagrid control with combo box controls. The following are example codes:

```
Dim cbCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
...
n = myGridView.RowCount - 1
For i = 0 to n
  cbCell = Me.myGridView.Rows(i).Cells(6)
  cbCell.DataSource = ' data source varies depending on rows
  cbCell.DisplayMember = "name"
  cbCell.ValueMember = "name"
Next
```

The problem I have is that the combo box are always displayed with null value (empty string) unless otherwise I click the combo box and select a item to display.

What I need is to set the first item (of the dropdown list) as default for each row. Since the data source for combo box are different, thus, the displayed default item may be different.

Answer (score 1):

You could changing the text of the cell to the specified string?

```
   cbCell.text = egCell.items(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to resolve the issue. Let me explain something about my question first. This "combo box" control is not bound to any property of its data grid's datasource. That's why I need to define its data source in codes in the form load event, as described in the question. The "combo box" is actually an instance of DataGridViewComboBoxCell, which does not have selected index property. I could not find out a way to get the first item's value of the assigned "combo box".

The solution is to cast or convert DataGridViewComboBoxCell to DataRowView. The following are my example codes:

```
Private Sub WorkOrderList_CellFormatting(sender As Object, 
  e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles
  WorkOrderList.CellFormatting

  Dim dgvc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
  dgvc = Me.MyDataGridList(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
  ....
  Me.MyDataGridList(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = CType(dgvc.Items(0), DataRowView).Item(0).ToString()
  ....
End Sub
```

Notice that if I directly to assign dvvc.Items(0) to datagrid's control's value, I got only class type name as a string. The string value of DataRowView's Item(0) is the first item's text in combo box. That's what I want.

I hope this answer may provide some help for other people in similar case.